# confusion about fubini theorem

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I want to integrate function $f(x,y)=e^{-2x+y}$ on region $A=${${(x,y) : y \leq 2x}$}. $f$ is continuous on measurable set so is measurable, $f$ is positive. So fubini theorem apply. Our integral is equal to iterated integral: $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{2x}e^{-2x+y}dydx$
after computation we are left with $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}1dx$ which is not integrable.

What is wrong?

Comment: [Fubini-Tonelli's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem#Fubini%E2%80%93Tonelli_theorem), which applies to non-negative measurable functions, tells you that all the iterated integrals have the same value, possibly $+\infty$ (i.e. they all diverge together).

Comment: but $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}1dx$ is not even $\infty$ it does not exist

Comment: It diverges to $+\infty$? i.e. you can make it as large as you want

Comment: no, look at the boundries, its from -$\infty$ to $\infty$, integral does not exist

Comment: You are integrating a constant one over that region. Think: $\int^M_{-M} \mathrm{d} x = 2M$ for all $M > 0$, and send $M \to \infty$.

Comment: haha im stupid, I thought about integral of x, thank you